# ¿No se me asigna el valor al atributo en laravel lumen?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

estoy intentando llamar al atributo pero me da como null si lo llamo desde otra función alguien sabe que puede estar pasando ??

```
 class ArchivoController extends Controller
 {

 public $usuario;

 function pasar(Request $request)

 {


  $data = $request->json()->All();

  $this->usuario = $data;     //si pongo debajo dd($this->usuario); me da 
                              // los datos correctos



  }


  function ver()
  {

  dd($this->usuario);   //<---- me da null cuando me debería dar los datos 
                        //      que le he asignado arriba


  }



  }
```

Comment: declara la variable $usuario como private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que no estás retornando ningún valor.
Te falta el `return` en los 2 métodos.

```
class ArchivoController extends Controller
{
    public $usuario;

    function pasar(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->All();

        $this->usuario = $data;     //si pongo debajo dd($this->usuario); me da 
                                    // los datos correctos
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    function ver()
    {
        // dd($this->usuario);   //<---- me da null cuando me debería dar los datos 
        //      que le he asignado arriba
        return $this->usuario;
    }
 }
```